# telnet command in nodejs not running(on windows)

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn nodejs. Trying to execute an example

```
    var server = require('net').createServer();
    var port = 4001;
    server.on('listening', function() {
           console.log('Server is listening on port', port);
    });
   server.on('connection', function(socket) {
           console.log('Server has a new connection');
           socket.end();
           server.close();
   });
   server.on('close', function() {
           console.log('Server is now closed');
   });
   server.on('error', function(err) {
           console.log('Error occurred:', err.message);
   });
   server.listen(port);
```

when i run this .js file - node ...js I get a message - server is listening on port 4001
now i cant type anything in console (windows) the tutorial says execute telnet localhost 4001. if i do ctrl+c and then type telnet localhost 4001 it gives err 'telnet is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Answer (score 2):

Open another console and run `telnet localhost 4001` there.

And to install `telnet`, follow these instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx